# Matrix in txt file - Java

Tags: java, file, matrix

I have a problem with matrix. I have a matrix in txt file. This matrix looks:

```
231 324 123
345 565 234
657 234 654
```

I want to replacement elements to form:

```
654 234 657
234 565 345
231 324 123
```

I have a algorithm with replacement elements: 3-1-i, where i is number of choosen element from array. I have a problem how I read file and save elements to array and how implement this loop. This is my try with reading txt file and saving elements to array:

```
    List<String[]> rows = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    while ((line = bfr.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] row = line.split(" ");
         rows.add(row);

       }
    System.out.println(rows.toString());
```

But I get `[Ljava.lang.String;@525483cd` as result.
 Can anyone help me with this loop and reading this matrix?

Comment: Did you make sure you took the red pill?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note : I used String s with newline characters `\n`, works the same way if the string is gotten from a file.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class file {
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

String s = "231 324 123 \n 345 565 234 \n 657 234 654";

StringTokenizer n = new StringTokenizer(s);
String [] arr = new String[9];
int nn = 0;
 while(n.hasMoreElements()){
    arr[nn] =  n.nextToken();
    nn+=1;
}

for(int iii = (arr.length -1); iii >=0 ; iii--){
   System.out.print(arr[iii] + "  ");

    if((iii % 3) == 0) {
        System.out.println();
    }
}

}



}
```

Output is

> 654  234  657
>   234  565  345
>   123  324  231

**Edit** To read the string from file

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

int i;
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("files.txt");
String n = "";

do {
     i = fin.read();
     n += (char) i;
   } while(i != -1);

   fin.close();
//String n now contains the contents of the file
}
```

Comment: It works great, but how I get String s in this from from file? The previous solution give me result
`654? 234 657
234 565 345
123 324 231`
Why '?' is there?

Comment: @edi233 I don't know why `?` is there oh. But I've posted a method of reading from file.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the actual address of the object .

```
//this is pseudo code btw
for each (String row : rows){
  file.writeline(row);
}
file.save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line: `System.out.println(rows.toString());` with a loop that iterates through the ArrayList and another for each String array within the ArrayList.

```
for (String[] row : rows)
{
   for (String num : row)
   {
      System.out.print(num);
   }
   System.out.print("\n");
}
```